# Exported Eclipse Android project won't run from Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, android-studio

I followed googles instructions and exported a test project from Eclipse by using the

Export -> Generate Gradle build files

opened up Android Studio and imported. After getting my support libraries working properly my project would compile with out any errors. **My problem started when I tried to run the app on my device**. When ever I try to run the app it directs me to use an AVD, never giving me the option to select my device. I obliged, created a new AVD but to no avail only to get build failed error. (I'll add the exact error when I can) **NOTE:** I can see my device is connected by clicking on "(6)Android" and the bottom left of the screen. I do see all logcat messages in verbose. I added `android:debuggable="true"`to my manifest but still nothing.

Confused I created a new project directly from Android Studio, hit run and bingo,...it gave me the option to use my device to run it or an AVD. Selecting either results in a successful launch of the dummy "Hello World" app. I think it may have something to do with build variants as my imported project doesn't specify "debug" vs "release" while the Android Studio generated project does.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: It has to be with the new Gradle build system. Oddly enough i have had the opposite experience. I have been using IntelliJ to build ANdroid apps for some time now, and actually Android studio doesn't require gradle files for those projects and builds and runs them perfectly fine. So this is probably owing to the differences between Eclipse and IntelliJ. Expect things to be smoother with newer releases.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question. Bit of a double whammy. Before installing Android Studio I updated my SDK via Eclipse (as recommended/required by google). Turns out by doing so a few items in my current projects got disconnected. ie. build paths, dependencies, ect. (you now have to place external Jar's in the src/libs folder)

Here is what I did to fix it.

1. In Eclipse, Preferences -> Java Built Path ->"Order and Export" tab. Make sure items are selected
2. If you have external Jars, manually copy and paste the jar in the libs folder of the project. (I did this in my Finder)
3. confirm the project launches via Eclipse
4. If it runs, export the project again by "Generate Gradle build files" (confirm overwriting existing files, if any)
   5.Open Android Studio and re-import the project. Again, confirming overwriting of any existing files. 
   6.Next to the run bottom at the top of the screen click on the drop down next to your project name. Click "Edit Configurations..." and select "show chooser dialog" if not already selected.

clicked ok to exit,..and PRESTO!!! I finally have a successful project migration.

Hope this saves someone else time.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i have experienced similar stuff on Eclipse, its quite buggy. Since Android studio is based on it i would expect everything. Still the best solution to everything is to reload project, refresh project or restart IDE.

Comment: Android Studio isn't based on Eclipse, it's based on IntelliJ IDEA (i.e. the "other" big Android IDE).

Comment: My mistake i thought of something else but Eclipse in general is quite buggy.

Comment: But as google said, Android Studio is currently only a "early access preview" and there are many bugs now. Searching or Reporting bugs here: http://tools.android.com/knownissues

Comment: I guess I just need to be patient. Once they work out some bugs I think Android Studio will be a huge improvement over eclipse.

Comment: Though for development in global i think Eclipse is the best, especially with all available plugins.